# Using discriminator in a entity that extends another

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, mapping

I'm trying to use a `Discriminator` in a entity that extends from another. This is the code I made:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="usuarios_externos.usuarios", schema="usuarios_externos")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *     "natural" = "Natural",
 *     "empresa" = "Empresa"
 * })
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"correo_alternativo"}, message="El correo electrónico ya está siendo usado.")
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt", timeAware=false)
 */
class Usuario extends BaseUser {
    ....
}
```

But I'm getting this error while ran the command `doctrine:schema:validate`:

> [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]   Entity
>   'UsuarioBundle\Entity\Usuario' has to be part of the discriminator map
>   of 'UsuarioBundle\Entity\Usuario' to be properly mapped in the
>   inheritance hierarchy. Alternatively you can make
>   'UsuarioBundle\Entity\Usuario' an abstract class    to avoid this
>   exception from occurring.

Any way to fix this? It's possible to use Discriminator in extended classes?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The answer is right there in the `warning` message!

Basically, it's telling you that `Usuario` is defined in a way that could lead to trouble. In its current form, this code lets you make an instance of `Usuario` and work with it. But wait a second. That's not defined in the discriminator map. So, what's going to happen when you try to persist it? **Boom!**... or at least it will throw an ugly exception.

Now, I know you probably didn't even think about instantiating `Usuario`. It's just a base class for `Natural` and `Empresa`, but **Doctrine doesn't know that**.

So, how can you fix it? There are two possible scenarios depending on your needs:

### `Usuario` should be instantiable

That is, users in your application can be an instance of `Natural`, `Empresa` or just plain `Usuario`. This is probably not the case, but it may apply to a future reader.

**Solution:** add `Usuario` to the discriminator map. This will make it possible for your users to be one of any of those three types.

```
 * ...
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *     "usuario" = "Usuario",
 *     "natural" = "Natural",
 *     "empresa" = "Empresa"
 * })
 * ...
```

### `Usuario` should *not* be instantiable

That is, users in your application can either be an instance of `Natural` or `Empresa`, but never `Usuario`.

**Solution:** make `Usuario` an `abstract` class. This will make it impossible for it to be instantiated.

```
abstract class Usuario extends BaseUser {
    ...
```