# Symfony / PHP - Entity inside other entity in Form Type class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms, symfony-2.7

I have the following problem. Entity **Payment** represents types of payment. So I can have for example: 'Credit Card' with 2€ fee, 'PayPal' with 1.50€ fee and so on.

Then I have entity **OrderPaymentItem** which stores payment type used in e-shop order. Why? I need stored payment for each e-shop order because when I change fee of payment, it use fee which was used by customer when he/she was completion order ... If I connect Payment directly to Order entity instead of to OrderPaymentItem, it recalculate old orders and it is mistake. When you change fee, it should change only in new orders ... But I don't know how to correct it. First look at these two classes:

The first entity is **Payment**:

```
class Payment
{
    protected $id;
    protected $method;
    protected $fee;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set fee
     *
     * @param integer $fee
     * @return Payment
     */
    public function setFee($fee)
    {
        $this->fee = $fee;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fee
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getFee()
    {
        return $this->fee;
    }

    /**
     * Set method
     *
     * @param string $method
     * @return Payment
     */
    public function setMethod($method)
    {
        $this->method = $method;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get method
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMethod()
    {
        return $this->method;
    }
}


AppBundle\Entity\Payment:
    type: entity
    table: payment
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        method:
            column: method
            type: string
            nullable: false
            unique: true
            length: 64
        fee:
            column: fee
            type: integer
            nullable: false
```

The second entity is **OrderPaymentItem**:

```
class OrderPaymentItem
{
    protected $id;
    protected $method;
    protected $fee;
    protected $paymentId;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set fee
     *
     * @param integer $fee
     * @return Payment
     */
    public function setFee($fee)
    {
        $this->fee = $fee;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fee
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getFee()
    {
        return $this->fee;
    }

    /**
     * Set method
     *
     * @param string $method
     * @return Payment
     */
    public function setMethod($method)
    {
        $this->method = $method;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get method
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMethod()
    {
        return $this->method;
    }

    /**
     * Set paymentId
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Payment $paymentId
     * @return OrderDiscountItem
     */
    public function setPaymentId(\AppBundle\Entity\Payment $paymentId = null)
    {
        $this->paymentId = $paymentId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get paymentId
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Payment
     */
    public function getPaymentId()
    {
        return $this->paymentId;
    }
}


AppBundle\Entity\OrderPaymentItem:
        type: entity
        table: order_payment_item
        id:
            id:
                type: integer
                generator:
                    strategy: AUTO
        fields:
            method:
                column: method
                type: string
                nullable: false
                length: 64
            fee:
                column: fee
                type: integer
                nullable: false
        manyToOne:
            paymentId:
                targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Payment
                joinColumn:
                    name: payment_id
                    referencedColumnName: id
                    onDelete: SET NULL
                    nullable: true
```

Originally I have following form builder in basket form:

```
$builder->add('payment', 'entity', [
              'label' => 'Platba',
              'class' => 'AppBundle:Payment',
              'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Payment',
              'property' => 'method',
              'multiple' => false,
              'expanded' => true
]);
```

You can see that these two classes are almost same. Only OrderPaymentItem contains relation to Payment - not required but good for back compatibility.

I need to correct it now and use OrderPaymentItem instead of Payment. I need to use list of Payments, but save it as OrderPaymentItem.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Since the two classes are almost the same, you can use [Doctrine discriminator](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance).

[Take a look at this](https://blog.liip.ch/archive/2012/03/27/table-inheritance-with-doctrine.html)

> When using a discriminator map, for example, if using Single Table Inheritance, your ‘mapped entity’ will be extending a base entity.

[This should help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049290/using-discriminator-in-a-entity-that-extends-another)

P.S : I hope it's not too late...